# What is the faster and most reliable way of communication between Windows-based C# and Linux-based Java applications?

Tags: apache-kafka, rabbitmq, ipc, messaging

I have server A which runs under Windows (C#), I have server B which runs under Linux (Java). I need to setup a fast and reliable way of interaction between these two servers. 
Requirements:

- The size of data is small (many small messages of kbyte or something)
- The rate is 1 message per second at least; good to have 1 per ms
- The order should be preserved
- Persistency not required
- Delivery confirmation - yes

Some options out of my head:

- Kafka / other messaging systems. The downsize is that I have to use a
  middleware in a form of server.
- Use Cloud queues from AWS or other cloud service. Can be costly?
- Own messaging via TCP messages (very time consuming, I guess there
  are open-source alternatives). No middleware.
- Somehow via shared filesystem?
- Setup Linux Server on Windows and.. what? Any special options if
  applications are sharing same host?

Comment: What is the expected behaviour if the target system is not reachable?

Comment: Client repeates the message until success, Server repeates some types of messages. Yes, message acknowledge is important.

Comment: Can you elaborate more about `interaction between 2 servers`. for cross-platform interactions,  you can expose API from B that can be called from A or any required client. You can use REST  or even gRPC

Comment: Nothing can beat raw TCP.

Comment: TCP or something like ZeroMQ, but to be honest, RabbitMQ can handle 1000msgs/sec just fine.